# Calculate entropy of image using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the entropy of an image using [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)).
In the case of a picture, Pi is the number of occurrences of the pixel I divided by the number of pixels. (This code is for gray level images only)

I wrote this code which has no errors, but it is too slow. How can I optimize it?

```
def Picalc(img,pixel):
    counter = 0
    for row in img:
        for col in row:
            if img[col].any()==pixel:
                counter+=1
    return counter / (np.shape(img)[0]*np.shape(img)[1])

def compute_entropy(img):
    im=imageio.imread(img)
    sum=0
    for i in range (0,256):
        if Picalc(im,i) != 0:
            sum += -Picalc(im, i) * np.log2(Picalc(im, i))
    return sum
```

Then i called the function:

```
print(compute_entropy('image.png'))
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything? Or it returns 0? Or it is so slow that you haven't seen it returning something yet?

Comment: I just noticed it's very slow which is why I don't see any output. How can I optimize it?

Comment: I'll answer. But one question, is: what do you mean by `img[col].any()`? I am pretty sure it is not what you think it is.

Comment: I actually used that because if I use `if img[col]==pixel` I get the error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: But `col` is already the value of the image at this point. `col` is a number between 0 and 255. The pixel value. So `img[col]` is just a random row in the image.

Comment: I changed it to `if col==pixel`   but it's still super slow

Comment: Yes, it is. The point was first to be sure what code you want to optimize, before optimizing it. Your first version was very very strange. And would have been harder to optimize (to vectorize). I wouldn't spend time to figure out how to vectorize a code that is not really what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem (since the reason why "it returns nothing" is just because it is too slow), is that you should never, ever, iterates pixels yourself.

Python is one of the slowest language on Earth (it is very efficient for an interpreted language, but still, it is an interpreted language). The reason why many fast application are written in python, is because we always make sure that the most time consuming loops are not really in python, but occur inside the internal code (in C) of some libraries.

That the whole point of numpy for example.

So, if you need to compute something on all pixels of an image (a numpy array), be sure that it is numpy that iterates on all pixels and does what ever need on all of them).

I surmise that this code

```py
def Picalc(img,pixel):
    counter = 0
    for row in img:
        for col in row:
            if img[col].any()==pixel:
                counter+=1
    return counter / (np.shape(img)[0]*np.shape(img)[1])
```

should really be

```py
def Picalc(img,pixel):
    counter = 0
    for row in img:
        for col in row:
            if col==pixel:
                counter+=1
    return counter / (np.shape(img)[0]*np.shape(img)[1])
```

(would not make it faster. But at least it would work. Otherwise you are counting the number of time that the value of a pixel is also the ordinate of a row that contains at least one non-black pixel. So, on most image, that means the total number of pixels, since all pixels have a value between 0 and 255... unless there is a completely black area in the 256 1st lines of the image, that is true for all pixels. Plus, if the image height is less than 255, that is even an indexation error. And, anyway, and more importantly, it means nothing relevant)

And that code contains 2 for loops that should be avoided. Numpy's role is to compute things on a whole batch of value, instead of one by one.
For example, if you want to test if a pixel value is 12, for all pixel of the image, instead of

```py
for row in img:
    for col in row:
        if col==12:...
```

You can directly compute `img==12`, which is a 2d array of booleans, with True value where the pixel are 12.

To count the number of pixels that are 12, you can therefore just

```py
(img==12).sum()
```

(numpy compare all pixels to 12. Then, sum all the value of the result. The result being an array of True/False value, with the convention True=1/False=0, that sum is the number of pixels that are 12).

Applying that to your problem

```py
def Picalc(img,pixel):
    return (img==pixel).sum() / (img.shape[0]*img.shape[1])
```

While at it, let's change also the other function

```py
def compute_entropy(img):
    im=imageio.imread(img)
    mysum=0 # Never name a variable `sum`: that is a python symbol.
    for i in range (0,256):
        pc=Picalc(im,i) # Put that in a variable, otherwise you are doing 3 times the exact same, heavy, computation
        if pc != 0:
            mysum += -pc * np.log2(pc)
    return mysum
```

### Second version

Note that this is using your own logic (iterating all possible values of pixels). But numpy already have a `histogram` function to compute probabily of occurence of each pixels.

```py
# p[k] is probability of pixel value being k:
p=np.histogram(im, bins=256, range=(0,256), density=True)[0]
# Filter out null values
p=p[p>0]
# Result
return -(p*np.log2(p)).sum()
```

A variant of that, is, using scipy

```py
import scipy.stats
p=np.histogram(im, bins=256, range=(0,256), density=True)[0]
return scipy.stats.entropy(p, base=2)
```

### Timings

| Method | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Your code | 1/2 hour |
| Optimized version of your code | 405 ms |
| Using histogram | 15 ms |

So, computation time gain factor = 120000

(Note: `scipy.stats.entropy` is not faster, since computation time is mainly in the histogram part. Just, it avoids reinventing the entropy formula)

Comment: ;-) : Edited 35 minutes after posting initially, just to add a table with comparison times, showing the original ran for ~30 minutes.

Comment: @9769953 :-)  it is also that I wanted to be sure that the result of my other versions were exactly the same as the one of the original code. The timing of the original code is more a side effect of that verification :D (if it were just for the timing, I would have computed partial entropy for just 10 possible pixels value, and then multiplied by 25.6; wouldn't be too far off.